# Ajax request to a Azure ASP.net web service for Excel add in

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, excel, azure

I'm currently trying to make an ajax POST call to a web service that is hosted on Azure from an Excel add in. The ajax request worked perfectly when I was testing on localhost but it now gives me a NetworkError when I try to make the call. The code I'm using is:

```
var user = {
     UserName: "username",
     Password: "password"
}

$.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "http://qa-verso-enterprise-service.azurewebsites.net/VersoApiService.svc/AddIn/Login",
        data: JSON.stringify(user),
        dataType: 'json',
        traditional: true,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (json) {
            console.log("Success");

        },
        error: function (er) {
            console.log("Error");
        }
    });
```

I tried to simulate the call on a jsfiddle. You can find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Uwcuz/4530/

I also tried making the call using DCH chrome extension and everything seems fine. chrome-extension://aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm/dhc.html
With POST method and data:

```
{
    "UserName": "username",
    "Password": "password"
}
```

And this does return that the username is invalid.

Reading a bit I added

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

to the web config of my web service but that didn't work.

I really don't know what else to do... Any opinions?

Comment: When you say it fails now - how do you mean? It worked in excel and suddenly stopped - or going against a new server - or?

Comment: I was running the web server locally, the ajax call had the url:

    url: "http://localhost:11881/VersoApiService.svc/AddIn/Login"

And that worked perfectly...